# The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, windows-server

I installed SharePoint Server 2013 on Windows Server 2012. My SharePoint Administration page looks perfect. The problem is that my user side web page gives me a problem. After I complete the wizard inside administration, I'm getting the following error when I am trying to open the Sharepoint Team Group Web site.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8521152
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +114

[ServerTooBusyException: The HTTP service located at http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14489026
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +622
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message) +0
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr) +78
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst) +37
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo, SPRequestSecurityTokenProperties properties) +1507
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForLegacyLoginContext(Uri context) +71
   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPWindowsClaimsAuthenticationHttpModule.PerformClaimsAuthenticationForUser(HttpContext context, SPFederationAuthenticationModule fam, SessionAuthenticationModule sam, WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity, SessionSecurityToken sessionSecurityToken, Boolean writeCookie) +295
   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPWindowsClaimsAuthenticationHttpModule.AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +688
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +182
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +183
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE John! Have you created a Web Application and a Site Collection where you are the site owner yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your Security Token Service is not configured properly (or is having issues).  MSDN has a good blog post about the various items you might check: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sykhad-msft/archive/2012/02/25/sharepoint-2010-nailing-the-error-quot-the-security-token-service-is-unavailable-quot.aspx

Comment: In my SharePoint Web Services Applicaton pools I am missing SecurityTokenServiceApplication

Comment: Is your STS created.  In PowerShell, do "Get-SPServiceApplication | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -Match "Security Token" }".  If it does exist, you can do this to try and re-provision the components: (Get-SPServiceApplication | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -Match "Security Token" }).Provision()